# 2d rigidbody falling from the collider when it is moved in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a box made of four rectangles. A 2D box collider is attached to each of the square. The box rotates in both the directions upon receiving the commands. The square inside the box has a rigidbody attached to it. The square rests on the box when pressed play however when I am rotating the box, the square jumps down the box and keep going down. Please suggest a resolution for it. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

After rotating the box
[image]

I looked at other answers and they all have suggested to slow the movement which is not possible in my case.

Comment: **How** is it moved? Please show your script for this. My guess: You are directly moving it via `transform.position` or in `Update` .. both breaks the physics ;)

Comment: And if that's not it, try changing the rigidbody's Collision Detection Mode option to one of the `Continuous` ones, best for not missing a collider at high-speeds.

Comment: @derHugo I am using transform.rotate in Update function.. should I change it to fixedUpdate?

Comment: @Philipp I have tried changing the collision type to continuous but it is still giving me the same issue. I think it has something to do with the speed of the outer box...

Answer (score 0):

I think you, you have to use edge collider 2D or make a make rectangle of 4 box collider 2d over the edges of your square (White square)

[image]